# Do I need to upgrade to Entity Framework from 4.0 to 5.0 to improve SQL generation with a TPT schema?

Tags: entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

I have an application using EF 4.0/.Net 4.0 and I'm using a TPT model, causing some performance issues when the size of data gets too large.
As far as I understand, .Net 4.5 is supposed to improve performance by adding support of automatically Compiled queries. In my case, what should I do to improve the performance of my application in the new SQL generator when using a TPT model.

My problem is that I can't find anything telling me if this is provided by .Net 4.5 or EF 5.0.

Just to let you know, I did migrate to .Net 4.5 and couldn't see any significant change in terms of performance. I checked the generated SQL for one of my slow request and it is exactly the same as with .Net 4.0. 
I also tried to migrate to EF 5.0 but couldn't see any improvement. Actually, as I don't use any type defined in EntityFramework.dll (v5.0), the assembly is not referenced (checked with reflector) and even not loaded at runtime.

Should I go on with migrating to EF 5.0 or is it more related to .Net 4.5 ?

Regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

**Entity Framework CTP: TPT Inheritance Query Improvements**

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/entity-framework-june-2011-ctp-tpt-inheritance-query-improvements/

Improve Performance with Entity Framework 5
EF5 features better query performance, support for enums and spatial data types, and much more

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/entity-framework/entity-framework-5-143875

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply !

If the improvement of query generator comes from EF 5.0 and not .Net 4.5, could you tell me why the reference to EntityFramework.dll is skipped by the compiler and the dll is not loaded at runtime ?